# C, atoi() generating Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, atoi

I'm using atoi() to get the status code from a header, but it's not working with the following input:

`" 404 Not Found\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nDate: Thu, 12 Dec 2013 20:53:22 GMT\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"`

**Shouldn't it stop reading at the first non-numerical character?** As described on: http://www-control.eng.cam.ac.uk/~pcr20/www.cppreference.com/stdstring_details.html

> atoi() will stop reading from str as soon as a non-numerical character has been read

According to the debugger, the code where the segmentation fault happens:

```
__NTH (atoi (const char *__nptr))
{
   return (int) strtol (__nptr, (char **) NULL, 10);
}
```

It's line 280 from stdlib.h, and the value of __nptr is:

```
__nptr  " 404 Not Found\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nDate: Thu, 12 Dec 2013 20:53:22 GMT\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" char *
```

---

**I would like to point out that the following inputs work fine (no segmentation fault):**

```
__nptr  " 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\nDate: Thu, 12 Dec 2013 21:13:24 GMT\r\nServer: sffe\r\nContent-Length: 943\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\nAlternate-Protocol: 80:quic\r\n\r\n"   char *

__nptr  " 302 Found\r\nCache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nExpires: 0\r\nLocation: http://br.godaddy.com/\r\nServer: Microsoft-IIS/7.0\r\nSet-Cookie: MemBotChk=false; path=/\r\nSet-Cookie: countrysite1=www; domain=godaddy.com; expires=Fri, 12-Dec-2014 21:15:09 GMT; path=/\r\nSet-Cookie: language1=pt-BR; domain=godaddy.com; expires=Fri, 12-Dec-2014 21:15:09 GMT; path=/\r\nP3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="COM CNT DEM FIN GOV INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR STA UNI IDC CAO OTI DSP COR C..."    char *
```

---

Actually, all inputs so far worked all right except for the one I mentioned in the beginning. **What could be causing segmentation fault?**

Removing the leading space doesn't make a difference. I also tried to add a null terminator after the response code, same thing happened. So I believe it's not `atoi()`, but something else. How to identify the problem?

---

**Valgrind results:**

Invalid read of size 1 in main in main.c:23

Address 0xf is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

- 1: *_*_strtol_l_internal in
  /build/eglibc-hkB3nk/eglibc-2.17/stdlib/../stdlib/strtol_l.c:298
- 2:
  get_web_content in /usr/include/stdlib.h:280
- 3: main in main.c:23

main.c:23 is just a call to get_web_content()

---

**The problem was that atoi() was called with a null pointer later.**

Comment: Perhaps you're not passing in the string you think you're passing in,  or you've previously trashed some memory. If this is on linux, run your program under valgrind to find the error.

Comment: I'm confused by how you are using `__nptr`. This works fine for me. `printf("%d\n", atoi(" 404 Not Found\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nDate: Thu, 12 Dec 2013 20:53:22 GMT\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"));`

Comment: @rkyser I'm not using __nptr, that's the code on stdlib.h that's giving the segmentation fault according to the debugger.

Comment: @Douglas Suggest showing a code snippet up to the `atoi()`.  Certainly it is not caused by `atoi()`.  BTW: Yes, "Removing the leading space" should not change things.

Comment: Please show the surrounding code in get_web_content(). Is the string on a malloc'd buffer? Could it have been freed?

Comment: Guess it's fixed then. You should post it as an answer by yourself instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a beginner's mistake really. in order to allocate memory for the response body, I called strcasestr to find the Content-Length: field. Only I didn't check whether or not the field had been found. The thing I don't get is why the debugger was showing the previous call to atoi().

**In case anyone with the same problem happens to stumble upon this question here's what I was doing wrong:**

```
fill_this->content_length = atoi(strcasestr(header_string + i, "Content-Length:") + 15);
```

And the solution:

```
char *temp = strcasestr(header_string + i, "Content-Length:");
if(temp == NULL)
   return;
fill_this->content_length = atoi(temp + 15);
```

Comment: For robust code, avoid the magic numbers like 15 and consider `strtol()` over `atoi()` for better error handling.